# Promises with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

I have questions about promises. I'm just starting to deal with them and it's not that easy to understand!

I'm trying to setup an authentication system for my app.

**RegisterPage**

`handleSubmit` looks like that:

```
handleSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault();     
  const { user } = this.state;
  //some code here
  userActions.register(user);
}
```

**UserActions**

```
function register(user) {
  userService.register(user)
    .then(
      user => {
        success(user);
      },
      error => {
        failure(error.toString());
      }
    );
  function success(user) { return { type: "REGISTER_SUCCESS", user } }
  function failure(error) { return { type: "REGISTER_ERROR", error } }
}
```

**UserService**

```
function register(user) {
  const requestOptions = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify(user)
  };

  return fetch(`/api/users/register`, requestOptions).then(handleResponse);
}

function handleResponse(response) {
  return response.text().then(text => {
      const data = text && JSON.parse(text);
      if (!response.ok) {  
          const error = (data && data.message) || response.statusText;
          return Promise.reject(error);
      }

      return data;
  });
}
```

**Question 1.** That code is "working" but not like I want. That way, even if the request success, I still can have error from the server, like duplicate username or something like that. I guess what I want is to return `Promise.reject()` not just if `!response.ok` but also if I have errors in the JSON returned right?

```
function handleResponse(response) {
  return response.text().then(text => {
      const data = text && JSON.parse(text);
      if (!response.ok) {  
          const error = (data && data.message) || response.statusText;
          return Promise.reject(error);
      }
      else if(data.errors) {
          return Promise.reject(data.message);
      }

      return data;
  });
}
```

**Question 2.** If everything's fine, should I `return data` or `return Promise.resolve(data)`? And why?

Comment: Where is React?

Comment: 1) Yes. Although you can also `throw` instead of `return Promise.reject`. And notice that you probably should check `response.ok` *before* using `.text()`. Also there's a `response.json()` method so that you don't need to call `JSON.parse` on the response text. 2) Use the simpler one.

Comment: ok, it's not really a React question, you're right.

Comment: ` Promise.reject()` will be called either your response HTTP code contains 4xx or 5xx error codes or if you have error in your logic in then

Comment: Hey, probably will be helpful: https://promisesaplus.com/

Comment: (2) It would be the same thing, because if function passed to `then` returns a promise, then that promise is resolved to determine the result. Reading Promise docs (like in the link above) is helpful to get the general idea, but it's pretty technical and once you start using them more you will see that they're much more straightforward than it seems.

Answer (score 2):

Checkout the documentation for `fetch` here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Checking_that_the_fetch_was_successful

It seems you should be using `.catch()` to get server errors and just use `throw new Error()` for having errors.

You don't really need to use `Promise.resolve` or `Promise.reject`.

To help refactor what you have, you can try this

```
function register(user) {
  const requestOptions = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify(user)
  };

  return fetch(`/api/users/register`, requestOptions).then(handleResponse);
}

function handleResponse(response) {
  return response.text()
     .then(text => {
       if (!response.ok) {
          const error = (data && data.message) || response.statusText;
          throw new Error(error);
       } else {
          const data = text && JSON.parse(text);
          return data;
       }
     })
     .catch(error => throw new Error(err));
}
```